# pandas: Transforming timestamp index to ISO week quickly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have a function that returns the index value of a pandas `Series` instance comprised of an array of `pd.Timestamp` values as an ISO week value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

timestamps = [pd.Timestamp('2014-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2014-02-01'), pd.Timestamp('2014-02-01')]
quantities = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
series = pd.Series(quantities, index=timestamps)

def timestamps_iso() -> np.array:
    timestamps_iso = []
    for timestamp in series.index:
        timestamp_iso = timestamp.isocalendar()[1]
        if timestamp_iso == 53: # fix ISO week number 53.
            timestamp_iso = np.random.choice([52, 1])
        timestamps_iso.append(timestamp_iso)
    return np.array(timestamps_iso)
```

**Can this be made quicker, or done in a more pandas style, please?** It takes a lot of time when the index is large to run.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question says month value, but the code says week value. I assume you're looking for the week value. You can access the week number on a datetime series with `.week`:

```
In [1]: timestamps = [pd.Timestamp('2014-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2014-02-01'), pd.Timestamp('2014-02-01')] 
   ...: quantities = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0] 
   ...: series = pd.Series(quantities, index=timestamps)                                                                                                                                                                                             

In [2]: series.index.week                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[2]: Int64Index([1, 5, 5], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Thanks -- that's what I needed. Much quicker.